# Wrapping a function that takes an array of pointers

Tags: python, c, interface, swig

I have a `struct a { }` defined. My C function takes an array of `struct a`  by reference and then fills data in it. So it accepts an argument `struct a **`.  I want to call this function from Python using a SWIG interface. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with SWIG and Python. I've set up the following test.h file to deomstrate:

```
struct a {
  int val;
};

static void populate(struct a **list) {
  int count = 0;
  // Terminate when NULL entry found
  while (*list) {
    (*list)->val = count++;
    ++list;
  }
}
```

The populate function takes a `struct a**` as you describe, assuming that the list is NULL terminated and does something to each element of the list.

The way I chose to expose this to Python was as a function that takes an integer, i.e. the size of the list to work with, and then returns the resulting list, since that's the nicest way of mapping the semantics of the "return via an argument" set up in my view.

I set up a basic module file:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}
```

then added a typemap that prepares an input list based on the size specified to the Python function:

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=1) struct a ** (int len=0) {
  len = (int)PyInt_AsLong($input);
  $1 = malloc(sizeof(struct a*)*(len+1));
  $1[len] = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    $1[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
  }
}
```

Basically it treats the argument as an integer, allocates memory for the array of pointers and then some memory for the objects that the elements themselves point to. (I allocated them individually so that SWIG/Python can handle the reference counting for each item individually, which is simpler than allocating one block for all the elements)

With that typemap written I then added another typemap, which is responsible for taking the result of calling the function and converting it back into a PyList:

```
%typemap(argout) struct a ** {
  // Push into PyList for return
  $result = PyList_New(len$argnum);
  for (int i = 0; i < len$argnum; ++i) {
     PyObject *element = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr($1[i]), SWIGTYPE_p_a, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
     PyList_SET_ITEM($result, i, element);
  }
}
```

It takes advantage of the `len` variable that we created in the in typemap, although since it's NULL terminated we could have just counted the length again. Then we populate each item in the Python list with a wrapped object (owned by SWIG/Python) for each of the `struct a` that we passed into the `populate` function. Note that if the type names are different you will need to change `SWIGTYPE_p_a` to the appropriate `SWIGTYPE`. (These can be found from the generated wrapper source).

Finally we need to de-allocate the memory we had for the list on the C side, with:

```
%typemap(freearg) struct a ** {
  free($1);
}
```

and then ask SWIG to wrap the header file itself, using these typemaps:

```
%include "test.h"
```

I compiled this with:

```
swig -python -Wall test.i
gcc  -Wall -Wextra test_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -o _test.so -std=c99 -shared
```

and then ran the following Python to check:

```
import test

r=test.populate(100)
print r[0].val
```

Several points to note from this example:

- There's no error checking, for example `test.populate("Hello world")` will do bad things, `PyList_New` can fail and if it does fail we need to release the individual elements, not just the list
- If the memory ownership semantics are different then you'll need to change `SWIG_POINTER_OWN` appropriately
- If you don't want to have to specify the size of the list on the Python interface (e.g. it's known or fixed somehow else) you can change the `numinputs=1` to 0 and set `len` accordingly in the in typemap.
- If your function takes the list and an integer specifying its length instead of using a NULL terminated list you can extend this to a [multi-argument typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_multi_argument_typemaps).

All the code needed to compile/run this example is included in this answer, but if you want it in one handy tarball I've also put it [on my site](http://static.lislan.org.uk/~ajw/pyarrout.tar.gz). The answer still works even if that link should break though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish I had found this question/answer a couple of days ago. I had to develop something similar and came up with almost the same solution as you. Just another lesson that most tech problems have already been solved before...